# How to debug C++ module/function call used in .net application?

Tags: c++, .net, dnspy

I'm currently debugging a .net application by using dnSpy. There is a function where I have call like this

```
<Module>.X.Y.Z.Initialize(ptr, ptr2, flag);
```

The function belongs to a DLL and appearently is a C(++) function call as I could find this by going to the module:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Unmanaged | MethodImplOptions.PreserveSig)]
internal unsafe static extern void Initialize(byte*, byte*, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] bool);
```

So my question is how can I analyze this function (Initialize)? Logically dnSpy is skipping it and IDAPro doesn't help me further since the DLL itself is a .net so I can't start a debugging session within IDA.

I've tried to create a Debug Time Travel Trace with WinDBG but it throws me an error when I'm ending the session and can't open the trace anymore.

Are there any suggestions how I can figure out or debug this function Initialize is doing?

Comment: Have you tried disassembling the dll with DotPeek or similar?